# Drawing an IplImage within an MFC Dialog Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, opencv

I have an MFC dialog application that I am using as the front end for some image processing with OpenCV 2.1.  I would like to move away from using the cvShowImage and place my image directly on the dialog box or a suitable container.  I've found examples that with a technique using an MFC SDI application with a View/Doc model, but I can't figure out how to convert that.

I'm curious if anyone has done this and/or knows where an example may live that does this?

Also, this is my first MFC application.

Thanks all.

Comment: "Place my image directly" doesn't mean much.  That normally requires a bitmap that you use in the dialog editor.  Rather incompatible with the notion of an image processing application.  When you dynamically create the image then you'll have to paint it when it becomes available.  And that requires calling cvShowImage().

Comment: Please excuse the shortcuts I used in my language.  Maybe the question needs to be more generic.  How to I render a bitmap to a control and what controls are available to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a CvvImage type in highgui with a drawtoHDC(or simialr) function that will draw into a bitmap